# Get EllipticCurveJsonWebKey from JSON in Jose4J

Tags: json, jwt, jose4j

I am using the [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home) for implementing token based authentication in my application. I would like to know, if there is any possibility to load JWK from a json stored in the DB.
I made folliwing steps:

1. Created a key: `EllipticCurveJsonWebKey key = EcJwkGenerator.generateJwk(EllipticCurves.P521);`
2. Create JSON from it: `key.toJson()`
3. Save the json-value to the DB.
4. Loading value from the DB.
5. In this point I get stuck. I don't know how to create a key with the data provided in the json.

Any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found a working solution from this [link](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/issues/34/distributing-keys).

I post the answer which worked for me:

```
    // Generate a new RSA key pair wrapped in a JWK
    PublicJsonWebKey rsaJwk = RsaJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048);

    // or an EC key, if you prefer
    PublicJsonWebKey ecJwk = EcJwkGenerator.generateJwk(EllipticCurves.P256);

    // A JSON string with only the public key info
    String publicKeyJwkString = rsaJwk.toJson(JsonWebKey.OutputControlLevel.PUBLIC_ONLY);
    System.out.println(publicKeyJwkString);

    // A JSON string with both the public and private key info
    String keyPairJwkString = rsaJwk.toJson(JsonWebKey.OutputControlLevel.INCLUDE_PRIVATE);
    System.out.println(keyPairJwkString);

    // parse and convert into PublicJsonWebKey/JsonWebKey objects
    PublicJsonWebKey parsedPublicKeyJwk = PublicJsonWebKey.Factory.newPublicJwk(publicKeyJwkString);
    PublicJsonWebKey parsedKeyPairJwk = PublicJsonWebKey.Factory.newPublicJwk(keyPairJwkString);

    // the private key can be used to sign (JWS) or decrypt (JWE)
    PrivateKey privateKey = parsedKeyPairJwk.getPrivateKey();

    // the public key can be used to verify (JWS) or encrypt (JWE)
    PublicKey publicKey = parsedPublicKeyJwk.getPublicKey();
```